# Proxy cache for Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, proxy, squid

I would like to configure a proxy-cache under WIN2008 R2. RRAS is enabled with also DHCP, DNS AND WINS. DHCP run only IPv4.

Any ideas or something ? I've searched the web but couldn't find something. I heard of a proxy named Squid but I never had success to install it.

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Here's what I want to do basicly : http://docwiki.cisco.com/wiki/Network_Caching_Technologies

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @BrentPabst I would like a system who work like this : If on computer A I go somewhere, let's say google.com, my browser need to download the logo, all the buttons, etc. I would like a system that computer B won't have to download that again from google.com but from a cache who can be between the network and RRAS (the router inside W2008). At the end of the month, my bandwitch usage will be lower and I will need to go on the Internet less often. Since I have severals computers this would be very good to have. I'd like this to work with .exe, .zip, anything from Internet.

Comment: I have no clue, never heard of this before. But the bandwidth utilization can't be too great if you have browsers that allow on the wire compression.

Comment: So If I download Google Chrome on computer A, I download it from google.com but If I go download it after on computer B, it will download from the cache (who's on the ethernet network) and not on the internet network. The connection stay local and by the logic, the bandwith usage will be lower. It better to see from this point of like when we download update from Windows Update or large stuff...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't installed it or played with it, but from the documentation here  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc995236.aspx it seems to indicate that Microsoft Forefront Threat Management Gateway 2010 has a caching forward proxy.  This should be what you are looking for.  I can't offer any more advice beyond that as I haven't used it.

Comment: i believe after 8 years squid becomes useless as for now more as 70% uses ssl.